# Stop Counting At a Specific Threshold?

Tags: python, function, pandas, numpy

I'm calculating a column based off of several other columns. However for when the cumulative sum of all the numbers  reach a particular threshold (in my case when I hit the top of the budget) I want to stop doing the calculations and return only 0 for everything after that in the column. I tried nesting functions and that didn't work instead it just says 'str' and 'int' couldn't be added. Here is what it looks like right now:

```
def total(PC):
    for C in PC:
        if np.cumsum(C) <= budget_var1:
            return pol_cost 
        else:
            C == 0
    def pol_cost(x):
        if 9500000 <= x.CRV or x.CRV < 50 or x.MDI <= MDI_var:
            return 0
        if (x.CI < 40 ):
            return x.CRV
        elif (60 <= x.CI <80):
            return x.CRV*((100-x.CI)/(100-var_var))**x.Cost_Escalation_N

df1['Policy_Cost_Y1'] = df1.apply(total, axis = 1)
```

I've tried several combinations of things but none were successful. The inner function pol_cost works perfectly fine when it stands alone. Since I'm trying to be as efficient as possible I don't want to change the values to 0 after they've been calculated. I want a hard stop once it hits my threshold (budget_var1) and then fill the rest of the column with 0.

EDIT: This is what df1 looks like with 'Policy_Cost_Y1' ( the column I'm creating) added for format reference:

```
   budget_var1 = 9


 CRV     MDI    CI    'Policy_Cost_Y1'
  1.5     80    30         2
  3.0     90    95         3
  4.25    75    67         4
  10.0    90    87         0
  6.5     40    55         0
  2.0     56    65         0
```

Comment: It would be easier if you include at least a part of your `df1` and an example of the desired output.

Comment: It might be easiest to initialize the entire column with zeros, then run down the rows, performing the calculation and `break`ing when appropriate.

Comment: Several issues: What's the purpose of the `C == 0` line? `pol_cost` is missing a final return statement and the `elif` could just be an `if`.

Comment: @FabienP I added an example output column if that helps at all!

Comment: What does df1 look like? at least show a pseudo df with same structure and dtypes.

Comment: @FabienP added! all are int or float, no strings

Comment: I feel it will be simpler to compute the whole `Policy_cost` column, then replace values with 0 where the cumsum is over your threshold. What makes you matter about efficiency for this task?

Comment: @FabienP it's going to be applied to an excel workbook with millions of rows and will also unfortunately have to be computed locally instead of on a server.

Comment: Well, can't help on this one, sorry and good luck. BTW, your question is lacking values for the `pol_cost` formula, like `var_var`, `MDI_var` and `Cost_Escalation_N`. With these it would be easier for other people to replicate your function and work on it.